# Handling a dynamic refresh token on JMeter

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, regex

I have recorded JMeter script for a website.

One of the HTTP request is the below screenshot where a refresh_token is already set as a hard-coded parameter when I recorded the script first time. This HTTP request uses this refresh token to post a request and obtain an access token and the access token is used in the subsequent API requests.

[image]

My problem is, the refresh token expires after 24 hours and since this refresh token is not obtained as a response from any of the previous HTTP requests, I am unsure how to use a regex extractor to corelate it.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If I were you, I would ask the developer to provide a test API that will return the token.

Answer (score 1):

The [access token](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/access-tokens) is something you're getting as the result of the [OAuth 2.0 authorization code flow](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow)

It's not a single request, it's a series of requests which you need to implement somehow:

[image]

the options are in:

- simulating the same requests sequence as the real browser does (can be recorded and replayed after applying some [correlation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html#correlate-start) of the dynamic parameters)
- or using [Azure Identity client library for Java](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/overview/azure/identity-readme?view=azure-java-stable) from suitable [JSR223 Test Element](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223)

More information: [How to Run Performance Tests on OAuth Secured Apps with JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-run-performance-tests-oauth-secured-apps-jmeter)